# How to compare 2 timing from dropdown list in webform?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to compare the start time and end time values to ensure that the end time can never be earlier than the start time. If it is earlier, an error message will be displayed. But I can never get it to work. Please help if possible. Appreciate it.

Below is my vb.net code :

```
Private Sub TimeChk(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Time1 As Integer
        Time1 = bkDDlist_strTime.SelectedItem.Value
        Dim Time2 As Integer
        Time2 = bkDDlist_endTime.SelectedItem.Value
        Dim msg As String
        If (Time2 < Time1) Then
            msg = "Invalid End Time"
        End If

    End Sub
```

---

The dropdown list HTML code. The start time label is "bkDDlist_strTime" and the end time is "bkDDlist_endTime"

[Dropdown list code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb50G.png)

---

After changing the code as suggested.

```
Sub TimeChk()
    Dim Time1 = Convert.ToDouble(bkDDlist_strTime.SelectedItem.Value)
    Dim Time2 = Convert.ToDouble(bkDDlist_endTime.SelectedItem.Value)

    If (Time2 < Time1) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid End Time")

    End If

End Sub
```

---

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="CompareValidator1" 
ControlToCompare="bkDDlist_strTime" ControlToValidate="bkDDlist_endTime" 
Display="Dynamic" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Double" Text="Invalid End 
Time"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

---

VB code:

```
Sub TimeChk()
    CompareValidator1.ValueToCompare = bkDDlist_endTime.SelectedItem.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you take a look at your question's formatting please? Code blocks should be formatted using the `{}` button above the text box

Comment: Show us the code that puts items in the combobox too

Comment: What is `SelectedItem.Value`? Where does `.Value` come from? What is `bkDDlist_strTime`? What data are you storing in its (Items Collection)? Why is this code in Form.Load?

Comment: Hi! To Caius question. The dropdown list values which are the time selection values.

Comment: @CaiusJard The dropdown list values which are the time selection values. -- <asp:Label ID="Label8" font-size="12pt" forecolor="White" font-name="arial" runat="server" Text="Start Time:" CssClass="timetxt"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="bkDDlist_strTime" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0800">0800</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>0830</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>0900</asp:ListItem>
                    ... till <asp:ListItem>1800</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Edit it into the question inside a code block so that it's readable

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry about it as I am very new to here. I have added the code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Only one of your items actually has a Value. How about using the value as the number of hours and the text as a nice presentation of the time, like this:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="8"  >08:00</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="8.5">08:30</asp:ListItem> 
...
```

And make your `Time1`, `Time2` as `Double`

And use `Time1 = Convert.ToDouble(bkDDlist_strTime.SelectedItem.Value)` because right now .Value is a string

And then not only can you do `Time2 < Time1` to work out of the times are the wrong way round (if they are, just swap them over, don't give the user an error.. Try and program to be helpful to the user instead of giving error messages all the time) but you can work out e.g. how long the linterval is by `Time2 - Time1`:

```
17 - 9.5 = 7.5 hours
1700 - 930 = 770 <-- it's not anything, not minutes, not hours, no sense to use it
```

Comment: I tried  what you have suggested but unfortunately I'm unable to get it working, the message box doesn't prompt saying invalid tinme.

Comment: You understand that you're writing a website, right? Websites don't have MessageBox.Show - the code runs on a server, so the only thing it would do is show a messagebox on a server in a datacenter thousands of miles away from the user, and the machine doesn't even have a desktop or a logged on user, or even a monitor atttached to it. And it would halt the code, crashing the site for everyone

Comment: I am new to this vb.net thing, so it's like on the job training thing. Any suggestions to get a prompt if the end time is selected before the start time? Thanks.

Comment: Just swap them round, don't bother the user with a prompt. Any errors we can solve for the user without bothering them, we should, otherwise we end up with software like Symbian Phone OS, where user is guaranteed to see at least 1000 notification, warning or error pop ups per day; very boring. If you're writing a website you have to do notifications to the user in JavaScript, really. You could calculate error messages and send html back to the user in your page response if you're not writing a single page app

Comment: I am trying to achieve whereby the user cannot cannot select the end time earlier than the start time or else it's not logical. Because the user wants to book the meeting room, but selecting the end time earlier than the start time maybe by mistake. Therefore I am trying to get a simple prompt saying "invalid end time" if the user mistakenly selected an earlier end time.

Comment: It really feels like you're not getting the point I'm making. *Constantly interrupting the user with error message notifications is **very annoying** - always look for ways to NOT use a messagebox*. This is a situation where you can easily fix the problem another way; swap them over, or set the end time = to the start time, or starttime plus 30 mins or something, or show the dropdown in a red border with a side label saying "end time is earlier than start time", anything that avoids a messagebox error. How about CompareValidator https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_validators.htm

Comment: I have heed your advice and use the CompareValidator but seems can't get it to work. I have include the code up above. Appreciate if you or anyone out there could point out my mistake and advise accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong in the fragments of code posted other than you still have a MessageBox.show in server side code. "Can't get it to work" is a very vague description of a problem

Comment: "Can't get it to work" I meant that in my CompareValidator code above, I can't  seems to get the error text to appear if the end time is earlier than the start time. The message box is no longer there under the CompareValidator code